# How is it possible to automate legacy applications without installing a local Power Automation application?

Tags: power-automate

Example: let's say you have an old client-server based app.  The client software is the only way to interact with the UI (no web-based options).  Traditional RPA has a local presence, so you could install the client software on a computer, alongside the RPA software, and immediately interact with the client software with RPA.

Power Automate, however, is Azure/cloud based so how would it interact with the local client software?  I'm not seeing a way to do this with UI Flows (or elsewhere) as these are only cloud based.

Answer (score 0):

you may look into Power Automate UI Flow for the same.